# visulaizar PDF em aplicação java - Embutido - Problema na renderização

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

Olá,

Necessito de visualizar PDF's na minha aplicação JAVA.
Depois de alguma pesquisa, pondo de parte os componentes pagos pareceu me que a melhor resposta seria esta:

[Displaying pdf in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040344/3792998)

O colega sugere o uso da biblioteca `[PDF.js][2]` a correr dentro de um `WebView`.
Consegui visualizar PDF's simples(onde só tem texto), mas não consigo visualizar PDF's com imagens. Parece que não consegue carregar o conteúdo do ficheiro completo.

Algumas imagens:

Exemplo original -  Usando demo do mozila ([link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aplicação Java -  Exemplo PDF com imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aplicação Java -  Exemplo PDF simples (só com texto):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código usado:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class BrowserShowPdf extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        //Change the path according to yours.
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        File file;
        try {
            file = new File(getClass().getResource("viewer.html").toURI());
            System.out.println("Url ->>>>>" + file.toURI().toURL().toString());
            engine.load(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrowserShowPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrowserShowPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        engine.getLoadWorker()
                .stateProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    // this pdf file will be opened on application startup
                    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        try {
                            // readFileToByteArray() comes from commons-io library
                            byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("D:\\Font Awesome Cheatsheet.pdf"));
                            String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
                            // call JS function from Java code
                            engine.executeScript("openFileFromBase64('" + base64 + "')");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 800);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Algumas ajuda?

Existe alguma maneira mais pratica para conseguir visualizar PDF's dentro de aplicações java?

Obrigado